# How does ListView binding work under the hood?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

We recently run into some concurrency issues working with an `ObservableCollection` bound to a `ListView`'s *ItemsSource* on iOS. Investigating this issue was a good excuse to dive into the Xamarin Forms sources, as I'm still getting my feet wet on this platform.

In Xamarin Forms, the ListView is derived from an [`ItemsView<Cell>`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ItemsView.cs). This class implements the *ItemsSource* property, as follows:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ItemsView<TVisual>), null, propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);

public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}

static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var element = newValue as Element;
    if (element == null)
        return;
    element.Parent = (Element)bindable;
}
```

Now I'm confused. Typically, you would assign an `ObservableCollection` or a flat `IEnumerable` to the *ItemsSource* property. These don't derive from `Element`... so how -does- binding to an ObservableCollection work?

Comment: Not trying to be a smart ass here, but why not check out the source? :) https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2.5.1/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I want to (as you can tell by me actually quoting the source in the question above), but I'm apparently not looking at the right things... The ListViewRenderer you refer to does not contain a single reference to the ItemsSource, so I'm not feeling particularly enlightened yet :)

Comment: My bad, was a bit too quick on the reply there

Comment: No problem, thanks trying to help out! I -am- probably missing a very basic mechanism.

Comment: I believe you're looking into the visual implementation of the control [let's say _concrete_] - the templated item (`ViewCell`) that visually represent that one corresponding on collection... What I've noticed looking the XF source code is that they use an MVC-like pattern to handle the visual elements and its changes. The approach to bound the [_abstract_] data to these visual elements (Where I guess your issue lives) I couldn't figure out how works too, indeed.